# React create two build output folder

Tags: reactjs, iframe, webpack

I need to create some iframe, but there is a lot of components from the current project that can be used.

So the question is how to configure webpack to create multiple builds, i.e one is standard build and second is iframe_build.

Reason for this approach is the reusability of components from the main project.

Is this even possible or I will need to start a new project from scratch and copy components from the main into a second project?

Comment: I suggest to create seprate project as a library, which will be consumed by two other projects. The common code should be extracted into the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after short investigation i found that 
best solution for keep iFrame generation on main project and reuse components without create new project is to **create public route** and create component that can be used to show content in **iFrame** on other domain.